# Properly configure IntelliJ to use Ruby in a Java Project

Tags: java, ruby, intellij-idea, rspec

How to I configure IntelliJ Idea so I can use Ruby in a primarily Java project?  (Specifically, I am using RSpec to drive my system tests.)

As far as I can tell, I have the Ruby SDK correctly configured in the project, but the very first line of my ruby code (`require 'open3'`) has warning lines under both words (`Cannot find 'require'`).

For what it's worth: I don't need to run Ruby from within IntelliJ; I just want to reduce the number of warnings so the screen isn't so cluttered and so I don't get into the habit of ignoring warnings.

[image: SDK Project Configuration]
[image]

Comment: You can add a JRuby facet to your Java module or configure a folder in question as a Ruby module.

Comment: Adding a Ruby module fixed the issue.